# XSL 2.0: count total number of unique values

Tags: xslt, xpath, syntax, count, siblings

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/CR-INT034-ADP-Garnishment_Disbursements_File-Outbound2">
  <wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:field>1111</wd:field>
  </wd:Report_Entry>
  <wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:field>2222</wd:field>
  </wd:Report_Entry>
  <wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:field>3333</wd:field>
  </wd:Report_Entry>
  <wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:field>2222</wd:field>
  </wd:Report_Entry>
  <wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:field>3333</wd:field>
  </wd:Report_Entry>
  <wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:field>1111</wd:field>
  </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

Here is the xslt I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/CR-INT034-ADP-Garnishment_Disbursements_File-Outbound2" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="2.0">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="no" method="text" />

<xsl:key name="entry" match="wd:Report_Entry" use="wd:field" />

<xsl:template match="wd:Report_Data">
    <xsl:value-of select="count(wd:Report_Entry | wd:field[ generate-id() = generate-id(key('entry', wd:field))])"/>     
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am trying to count the unique values. So in the example above, the answer should be 3 and I am getting 6.

I tweaked the answer originally given to make it work in 1.0, but I can't use 1.0 I have to use 2.0. Is there any way to get this to work in 2.0 or am I just out of luck?

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Thanks,

Sarah

Comment: For your current stylesheet, you should use `count(wd:Report_Entry[ generate-id() = generate-id(key('entry', wd:field)[1])])`. Your stylesheet is currently counting the number of `wd:Report_Entry` elements (6) and the `wd:field` elements who's `generate-id()` is equal to the `generate-id()` of the node selected from the key using  the `wd:field` element that is a child of that `wd:field`(which doesn't exist, so it selects nothing from the key), resulting in a count of 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using XSLT 2.0, you can just use `distinct-values()`...

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/CR-INT034-ADP-Garnishment_Disbursements_File-Outbound2" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="no" method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(distinct-values(wd:Report_Entry))"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
3
```

Comment: Fantastic!!! This was exactly what I needed. Kudos to you both! This was my final code:                                          <xsl:value-of select="count(distinct-values(wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry/wd:field)"/>

Answer (score 2):

The following uses [`xsl:key`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#key) and the [Muenchien method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) to get a distinct list of the `wd:Report_Entry` elements, and then uses [`count()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-count)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/CR-INT034-ADP-Garnishment_Disbursements_File-Outbound2">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="entry" match="wd:Report_Entry" use="wd:field" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of 
             select="count(/wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry[
                      generate-id() = generate-id(key('entry', wd:field)[1])])"/>     
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I had to modify it a bit to get it working right, but it is now working. Thanks so much. You are awesome!!! Final code: `<xsl:key name="entry" match="wd:Report_Entry" use="wd:field" />` `<xsl:template match="wd:Report_Data">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(wd:Report_Entry[ generate-id() = generate-id(key('entry', wd:field))])"/>     
    </xsl:template>`

Comment: This didn't work for 2.0. Could you take a look and see if you can find a solution to work in 2.0. I've edited my question to include better xml and xslt.

Comment: I had misplaced the predicate filter(was being applied to the result of the `generate-id()` instead of the set returned from the `key()`, which happened to work when running with Saxon when I tested. I have updated it to correct the expression, so it should run as either a 1.0 or a 2.0 stylesheet with any XSLT engine.